# Does Rancher 2.5+ logging support Grafana Loki?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, rancher, fluent-bit, grafana-loki

I'm trying to setup logging using the new rancher 2.5 logging system, that's using the Banzai operator.
I was thinking to use the Banzai Operator for ingestion and push to a Grafana Loki  output.

The problem is that I'm getting some "entry out of order" errors on the loki side and I'm not sure if that is caused by rancher not supporting loki by default so that causes problems or if this is some config related issue on loki side.

The documentation is confusing:

1. On one hand on the banzai cloud one-eye logging operator documentation , loki is supported as an output
   https://banzaicloud.com/docs/one-eye/logging-operator/configuration/plugins/outputs/loki/
2. On the other hand the rancher documentation there's an example on how to deal with "unsupported" outputs by deploying another fluentbit container.
   https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/logging/v2.5/

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know what's the meaning of "supported" , or "unsupported" in this context? Is it just referring to UI support in rancher?
2. Is rancher using a different build of the banzai cloud operator that's scaled down and doesn't have all the features?
3. Can the "entry out of order" be caused by the fluentbit config or is that something on loki side?

My Cluster output looks like this, (taken from the banzaicloud documentation):

```
spec:
  loki:
    buffer:
      timekey: 1m
      timekey_use_utc: true
      timekey_wait: 30s
    configure_kubernetes_labels: true
    url: http://mylokihost
status:
  active: true
```

Comment: I'm also curious to find out.

Comment: I am experiencing the same behavior. It seems like it's unsupported out-of-the-box because the Cluster Explorer > Logging > ClusterOutputs > Create form does not have an option for Grafana Loki as a provider.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I've managed to do it It is as easy as:

```yaml
spec:
 loki:
   configure_kubernetes_labels: true
   url: http://10.43.14.83:3100
```

The support is there by default by banzai cloud, just the ui and documentation are ... bad. I had to dig through the operator code and found the good one.

One other thing I found is that filters don't work as expected, in the flow configuration.